# implementing Action Listener interface

Tags: java, swing

the first code prints the string `m` when `m` changes,
but when I remove the first if statement as shown in the second code I am not able to print m when it changes.
the codes to the program are given below.

**code 1**

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
    class firstgui extends  JFrame implements ActionListener{
       private JTextArea textarea;
       private JTextField textfield;

       static String m="bye";

firstgui() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    textfield = new JTextField(20);
    add(textfield);
     textarea = new JTextArea(5,20);
     add(textarea);
     textfield.addActionListener(this);         
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String text= textfield.getText();
    m=text;
    textarea.append("aman: " + text + "\n");
    textfield.setText("");
}

public static void main(String args[])
{ int t=0; 
    firstgui a = new firstgui();
    a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    a.setVisible(true);
    a.setTitle("gui");
    a.pack();
    while(true) 
    {
        if(m.equals("bye"))
        {
            System.out.println(m);
        }
        if(!(m.equals("bye")))
            System.out.println(m);
    }       
  }
 }
```

**code 2**

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
      class firstgui extends  JFrame implements ActionListener{
   private JTextArea textarea;
    private JTextField textfield;

    static String m="bye";

    firstgui() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    textfield = new JTextField(20);
    add(textfield);
     textarea = new JTextArea(5,20);
     add(textarea);
     textfield.addActionListener(this);        
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String text= textfield.getText();
    m=text;
    textarea.append("aman: " + text + "\n");
    textfield.setText("");
 }

  public static void main(String args[])
 { int t=0; 
    firstgui a = new firstgui();
    a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    a.setVisible(true);
    a.setTitle("gui");
    a.pack();
    while(true)
    {            
        if(!(m.equals("bye")))
        System.out.println(m);
    }       
  }
 }
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: You should make clear to the reader of your question what the actual result of your code is and what is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

There are different threads involved with your application one is `event dispatching thread` other is `main thread`.

actionPerformed is executed in `event dispatching thread`

busy-looping `while` is executed in `main thread`

Changes made by one thread are not visible to other thread. you need to use `volatile` keyword to make variable updates guaranteed to be seen by other threads.

some thing like `static volatile String m = "bye";`

It is advisable to use `wait/notify` for thread communication

**EDIT:**

The reason first code part worked because println got executed.

```
if(m.equals("bye"))
{
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

As println is syncronised on the `this` object, it triggered happens-before relationship for the main thread. because of which latest value of m is read.

You can check more in [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility)

`Synchronized` and `volatile` constructs form happens-before relationships
 The results of a write by one thread are guaranteed to be visible to a  read by another thread only if the write operation happens-before the read operation.

Comment: that volatile thing actually worked so thanks ravthiru, but in the first code that i posted it was working without using the keyword "volatile" can help me understand why is that!

Comment: See the edit in the answer, just println inside while loop should make second part also work.